# Sphinx can't locate conf.py but it is there

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to execute `sphinx-build`, but I get this error:

```
(AttractoraVenv) stw041269:AttractoraProject hugovillalobos$  sphinx-build -b html source build

Application error:
config directory doesn't contain a conf.py file (source)
```

But, as you can see, the file is right there:

[image: file tree]

I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Assuming your current directory is `source`, try `sphinx-build -b html . build`

Comment: Can you give me some feedback on the answer? Do you want it written slightly different or including the specific solution together with the general case? (I didn't add the localized solution that StevePiercy left in the comments because I thought it wouldn't be necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for `sphinx-build` is:

> `sphinx-build [options] <sourcedir> <outputdir> [filenames …]`

Notice the rules for discovery of `conf.py`:

> [sphinx-build looks for `<sourcedir>/conf.py` for the configuration settings. (...)](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#description)

So if you are executing `sphinx-build` from the `/docs` folder (named `/documentation` in your case) you would write:

`sphinx-build -E -b html -d build/doctrees source build/html`

```
C:.
├───docs <<-- Execute sphinx-build from this directory!!
│   │  
│   ├───build
│   │   ├───doctrees
│   │   └───html
│   │       ├───_sources
│   │       └───_static
│   │  
│   └───source
│       ├───_static
│       └───_templates
│
└───your_package
    └───__init__
```